# SQL Can connect by server name but not by instance name

Tags: sql

I just install SQL 2017 in two servers with default options. I also have configured the cluster role in both servers and activated the Allways On option.

Testing the enviroment before beging creating datasbase, i try to connect with SQL Management console to instance default name (select @@servicename is correct > MSSQLSERVER) and i cant connect. But i can connect with server name and cluster name in both servers.

I tried:

SERVERNAME\MSSQLSERVER

MSSQLSERVER

Why cant i connect to instance name?

Thanks,
Regards

Comment: Is the `SQL Server Browser` service running?

Comment: Ensure your SQL Server instance name has a registered service principal name (SPN) for Kerberos authentication.  [See this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/register-a-service-principal-name-for-kerberos-connections?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: just a blind stab, but you have to enable TCP connections for each instance and restart it, if you haven't already.

Comment: SQL server browser is already runnig and TCP is also enable. Im checking the SPN Automatic SPN Registration. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

```
setspn -L domain\sqlserver
```

[image]

Should the instance name appear?

Besides, should i must change the default instance name MSSQLSERVER to another more appropriate before proceeding with the rest of the configuration ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).